# Deleted items in calendar reappear after one day

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-calendar, outlook

I have a SharePoint calendar that's synced with Outlook. When the client deletes an item, it reappears the next day. This has occurs whether she deletes it from SharePoint or Outlook.

Comment: interesting, can you disable the sync with outlook?

Comment: is there any workflow on the calendar list that might recreate item?

Comment: @Colbs - I don't think disabling the sync is an option. I can try to get clients' consent on that, but it doesn't seem likely. I did however got some users to go in and remove the sync with their outlook accounts and re-sync, but the issue was still there.

Comment: @Danilo - There are no workflows in this site. Actually, after checking with designer, there are no workflows in the site at all (something I have never seen before).